# Audacity: calculate exact amplification

Tags: audacity

Imagine I have 2 audio files. They contain same audio but one of them was amplified using Amplify effect of Audacity. I don't know the value used. Is it possible to calculate exact dB value used to change one file comparing it with original? How?

Answer (score 5):

If the amplification was linear, and didn't result in clipping, then comparing any given peak value (in Audacity) between the two files will give you the information.

Answer (score -3):

Try amplify in the second file.  The dB needed will bring it to the first files level.

Now if you compress or process the files otherwise the amount might be different than just amplify would use without the processing.

Note that while the levels are the same the loudness may well differ.
See LUFs to learn more about loudness standards and how they differ from levels.

Comment: Loudness standards have nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: So what.  I added a useful lagniappe in addition to the answer of the question.